# input type text create dynamic text divider inside text box

Tags: text, input, types

[this is the pic][I want the " | " to be a text divider inside the text box...
here is the html code 
input type="text" id="psize" name="size" required size="30" placeholder="size1 | size2 | size3 | size4"

so the user can input his value like this: small | medium | large. with the " | | is already there
    ]

I want to implement a separator/divider between each text with a pipeline symbol for e.g. " | " inside my text box..

Comment: `textInputElement.value = textInputElement.value.replace(/\s/g, '|');`

Comment: I'm new to this. where exactly do i have to add this line?

Comment: Yeah.... dynamically means you're going to have to learn JavaScript. You can get an Element a bunch of different ways. `document.getElementById('psize')` could be in the place of where I was generically writing `textInputElement`. You probably want to do that based on a user action like `onkeyup` as well.